# ARM64 linux hangs during boot - sometime after 5.4.0-81

Tags: boot, changelog

I have an ARM64 Parallels VM on an M1 mac. With kernel 5.4.0-80 and -81, everything is fine. Using -84 -86 there are several points during boot where it just hangs for 2 minutes, for a total of nearly 6 minutes as opposed to ~30 seconds at most.

I was unable to find release notes for the specific versions between there. Does anyone know what changed that specifically impacts this, if there is a work-around, or if not, whether there's a planned fix for it (and how can I find out when it's safe to upgrade).

If I had a guess, I'd say this may have something to do with PRNG - the first hang has messages that seem to implicate the random system. The first 2 minute hang is after "random: crng init done". The second 2 minute hang is between "EXT4-fs (dm-0): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)" and  "EXT4-fs (dm-0): re-mounted. Opts: (null)" The third 2 minutes is in "systemd-udev-settle.service" according to the systemd blame report.

Comment: You have provided no OS & release details, nor if you're talking about a GA kernel or HWE kernel (ie. the 5.4 kernel is used by different OS & releases and we don't know what you're talking about; the detail of GA & HWE would allow us to have a better idea if you'd provided that; however OS & release specifics would tell us that too if you'd provided it).

Comment: This is Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to have been fixed at some point between 5.4.0-81 and 5.4.0-88. Upgrading to the latter does not exhibit the problem.

Comment: I don't have any citations or documentation BECAUSE THE QUESTION *ASKED* FOR DOCUMENTATION/RELEASE NOTES AND NOBODY REPLIED!!!